# Chuck IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: android, androidx

I make a simple app, that uses http. For debug previously I used Chuck library. But now, when I try to open http-package from Chuck I get exception and I don't understand why.
You can see the project here: https://github.com/FirstSpectr/Sandbox

````
    Process: ru.spectr.kotlinsandbox, PID: 4699
    java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class 'com.readystatesoftware.chuck.internal.ui.TransactionActivity' does not implement interface 'androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner' in call to 'androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner.getLifecycle()' (declaration of 'androidx.lifecycle.LiveData' appears in /data/app/ru.spectr.kotlinsandbox-cFhy1fESF3ecXGlmQrM-Yg==/base.apk!classes2.dex)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.observe(LiveData.java:172)
        at androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.setCallback(LoaderManagerImpl.java:100)
        at androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl.createAndInstallLoader(LoaderManagerImpl.java:400)
        at androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl.initLoader(LoaderManagerImpl.java:421)
        at com.readystatesoftware.chuck.internal.ui.TransactionActivity.onCreate(TransactionActivity.java:91)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)```
````

Answer (score 0):

I found problem dependency: 
implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0-alpha02'
After deleted chuck work fine